# STM32 Device_only USB_OTG

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I a working on a project around the STM32H7 (Nucleo STM32H743ZI2) on which I am using the user USB to communicate through CDC interface.
Everything is working fine, however, I just noticed that this User USB port is not powering the board. I am pretty sure initially it was, but well it's no longer the case.

what is the CubeMX settings to enable this user USB port to power the board? The goal is to use this USB port to connect to the PC communicating with the board (and not the STLINK USB).

right now I have the USB_OTG_FS set to Device_Only, activate_VBUS set to VBUS sensing and activate_SOF is enabled.

thanks!

Comment: nvm, not possible per documentation. oh well

Comment: If you think this is supposed to be supported, study the published board schematics until you understand how it is supposed to work.

Comment: On the STM32F4 Discovery board, I usually use a jumper wire to bridge the user USB VBUS to the 5V -> 3V regulator. Not sure if that's possible on your board.

Comment: I read the doc again and it clearly says that the User USB cannot be used to power the board

Comment: Please provide links to relevant data sheets plus section and page numbers so others can benefit/. Additionally, saying WHY this is the case (which may require you to look at schematics, would be informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the Nucleo doc for my H743ZI2 again and it clearly says that the User USB cannot be used to power the board.

THis is more of a limitation of the development boards rather than a limitation of the USB OTG itself.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide links to relevant data sheets plus section and page numbers so others can benefit/. Additionally, saying WHY this is the case (which may require you to look at schematics, would be informative. This also has the advantage of making the answer useful enough to be not much more than a comment.

Comment: I missed this comment. ugh sorry. Please refer to chapter 6.6.6 of the Nucleo User Manual ref. UM2407 (MB1364) page 27/50. Quote: "Warning: USB Micro-AB connector (CN13) cannot power the Nucleo- 144 board. To avoid damaging the STM32H7, it is mandatory to power the Nucleo-144 before connecting a USB cable on CN13. Otherwise, there is a risk of current injection on STM32H7 I/Os."